# SVN: Folder already under version control but not comitting?

Tags: svn

```
mark@mark-ubuntu:~/myproject$ svn stat
?       runserver.sh
?       media/images/icons
?       apps/autocomplete
mark@mark-ubuntu:~/myproject$ svn add apps/autocomplete
svn: warning: 'apps/autocomplete' is already under version control
```

`svn stat` says its not under version control, so I try to add it, and then it tells me it is. When I do an `svn ci`, it doesn't get comitted, and doesn't show up when I try to browse to repository online.

How do I get it to commit?

Comment: Does the "autocomplete" folder contain a broken ".svn" subdirectory? Also, did you cleanup? :)

Comment: Have you tried a: svn cleanup, just a stab in the dark?

Comment: I ran into this issue when I had copied a checked in directory to another folder in my project. Deleting the old .svn works!

Comment: I forcefully added the files: `svn add --force /path/to/file`, or if you want to add directory recursively: `svn add --depth infinity --force /path/to/directory`.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Copy problematic folder into some backup directory and remove it from your SVN working directory. Remember to delete all `.svn` hidden directories from the copied folder.

Now update your project, clean-up and commit what has left. Now move your folder back to working directory, add it and commit. Most of the time this workaround works, it seems that basically SVN got confused...

Update: quoting comment by [*@Mark*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65387):

> Didn't need to move the folder around, just deleting the `.svn` folder and then svn-adding it worked.

Comment: Didn't need to move the folder around, just deleting the `.svn` folder and then svn-adding it worked.

Comment: +1 for making my day ;-) As Mark said, for me it was enough to remove the .svn directories within the problematic folder.

Comment: now that you only have .svn in top folder, you cant do this BS, if metadata is corrupt, you are toast

Comment: uncheck the parent folder (apps/autocomplete) from the list if already commited

Comment: Follow up question. After deleting .svn and moving it to the desired location. How to make SVN ignore certain file formats (Ex. xml) for commit in the new location?

Comment: what is svn-adding?

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar-looking problem after adding a directory tree which contained .svn directories (because it was an svn:external in its source environment):
svn status told me "?", but when trying to add it, it was "already under version control".

Since no other versioned directories were present, I did

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name '.svn' -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

to remove the wrong .svn directories; after doing this, I was able to add the new directory.

**Note**:

- If other versioned directories are contained, the find expression must be changed to be more specific
- If unsure, first omit the "-exec ..." part to see what would be deleted

Comment: While this answer worked for me, the first time I used it, I was in the wrong folder and got things into quite a mess. Seems like a good place to remind people to "measure twice, cut once" i.e. double check the details before running this one.

Comment: I recommend the 'if unsure' to be  `... -exec echo {} \;` so you can get your -exec switch working well also.

Comment: also recommend adding a `-type d` to the find.  Call me picky until your `rm -rf` goes a bit too far.   Other than my nitpicks - I think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

A variation on [@gauss256's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245736/623735), deleting `.svn`, worked for me:

```
rm -rf troublesome_folder/.svn
svn add troublesome_folder
svn commit
```

Before Gauss's solution I tried [@jwir3's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4939078/623735) and got no joy:

```
svn cleanup
svn cleanup *
svn cleanup troublesome_folder
svn add --force troublesome_folder
svn commit
```

Answer (score 14):

(1) This just happened to me, and I thought it was interesting *how* it happened.  Basically I had copied the folder to a new location and modified it, forgetting that it would bring along all the hidden .svn directories.  Once you realize how it happens it is easier to avoid in the future.

(2) Removing the .svn directories is the solution, but you have to do it recursively all the way down the directory tree. The easiest way to do that is:

```
find troublesome_folder -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried performing an svn cleanup?

Comment: Ive ran too into this problem. Then tried `svn cleanup` and it didnt help it.

Answer (score 3):

Check for a directory 'apps/autocomplete/.svn'.  Move it somewhere safe (in case you need to restore it because this did not work) and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in case you have installed *Eclipse(Luna) with the SVN Client JavaHL(JNI) 1.8.13 and Tortoise*:

**Open Eclipse:
First try to add the project / maven module to Version Control 
(Project -> Context Menu -> Team -> Add to Version Control)**

You will see the following Eclipse error message:

*org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Entry already exists
svn: 'PathToYouProject' is already under version control*

**After that you have to open your workspace directory in your explorer, select your project and resolve it via Tortoise
(Project -> Context Menu -> TortoiseSVN -> Resolve)**

You will see the following message dialog:
"*File list is empty*"

Press cancel and refresh the project in Eclipse.
Your project should be under version control again.

Unfortunately it is not possible to resolve more the one project at the same time ... you don't have to delete anything but depending on the size of your project it could be a little bit laborious.

Answer (score 0):

For me doing a svn update, followed by svn commit worked. There were no .svn folders present in folder which was failing to add.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the problematic file, Commit, rename it to the original name and commit