# SVN: Unable to commit?

Tags: svn, git-svn, commit

I am trying to add several folders and commit. In the first iteration of the project, it did have folders having the same names of those I am trying to add.

When I do `git add src`, it tells me that `svn: warning: 'src' is already under version control`.

Committing didn't put them on the repo.

I tried `git add src --force`, I couldn't commit either, as svn thinks that the repository is unchanged. What's going on here?

Note: The current repo does NOT have a src directory, all it does have is a Makefile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939045/svn-folder-already-under-version-control-but-not-comitting This question have answer

Comment: It acutally doesn't. I tried that work around