# .so files are not committing to SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

Possible duplicate

[I fail to commit a .so library file using subclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892248/i-fail-to-commit-a-so-library-file-using-subclipse)

I am developing an android application and in that I am trying to add some .so files from UlraliteJ framework. When I googled, I could see that .so files are ignored by SVN by default. So, I uncomment the line global-ignores in the config file of /.subversion folder as per this example

http://blog.keksrolle.de/2010/03/01/svn-ignores-file-extension-so-by-default-which-corrupted-my-build.html.
 But, even then I was not able to commit them.

After that, I found the above post, so following that, I manually added .so files to version control and they have been added now.

But, now my problem is that they are not getting committed to SVN still. It fails with the following message,

```
 svn: Commit failed (details follow):
 svn: File not found: transaction '1635-1c5', path '/SVNfolder/trunk/OS_Android/SVNProject/libs/armeabi/libmlcrsa12.so'
```

If any body knows the answer, can you please share it with me

Comment: Is the `armeabi` directory checked in?  Have you run `svn cleanup`?  Have you tried backing up your working copy (important) and then `svn update` to resolve conflicts?

Comment: Yes, I have tried svn clean up and svn update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to commit after a day of effort. Thanks to this guy,

[SVN: Folder already under version control but not comitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939045/svn-folder-already-under-version-control-but-not-comitting)

All you need to do is, take a back up of your project. Go to the problematic folder. In my case it was armeabi folder inside /lib of my project. View hidden files. There will be a .svn folder. Delete that.

Then revert back the .so files, clean the project. Add them back to the version control. Now along with the files, one more file named svn-commit.tmp.save is also created. Don't worry. Just commit the whole folder. Thus it is committed now.

How ever, I din't exactly know the need for deleting .svn folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this annoying problem using Eclipse and SVN

1. select the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective.
2. choose the right folder where the .so files should be in the "SVN Repositories" view.
3. right click and choose the "import" menu
4. in the pop out dialog, choose a local path which containing the .so files, input the commit comment and hit OK button.
5. now the .so file are at the correct position.