# file/folder "is already under version control"

Tags: svn

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939045/svn-folder-already-under-version-control-but-not-comitting) but from what I can tell SVN now has only one .svn folder and the solution doesn't work.

I'm trying to release a new version of my project - a WP plugin on the WP repo. I copy-paste the built files into trunk/ and then do `svn add trunk/*`. This is the error:

```
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/LICENSE.txt' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/README.txt' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/admin' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/includes' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/index.php' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/languages' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/plugin-name.php' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/public' is already under version control
svn: warning: W150002: 'trunk/uninstall.php' is already under version control
```

I tried to delete the trunk folder, even deleted the whole repo and checked out again. Please help!

Comment: Why do you need to `svn add` files that are already under version control? Maybe you should be using `svn update`, `svn status`, `svn diff` and finally `svn commit` to commit the new version to the repository.

Comment: Because that's what Wordpress tells you to do: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/#starting-a-new-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You are adding stuff that already exists.  The simple answer is to force it:

```
svn add * --force
```

`--force` will "ignore already versioned paths".  It will also work recursively, meaning that all unversioned files will be added to your repository.  You'll still need to `svn commit` when you are ready.  If you get any warnings, that something has already been added, you can just ignore it.

---

Here's a more durable solution which I think will work better for you:

It looks like you have an external project and you are tracking the changes in releases.  It looks like you want to replace everything with a pristine copy of the upstream release.

IFF that's true, follow these steps:

1. From your working copy, delete all local content.  This will wipe any local changes:

```
rm -rf *
```

2. Extract the code you want to be in your repository, to your repository.  If it's just another directory, then just copy it.  I am extracting a tarball to the current directory.

```
tar -xf ../project-release_1.2.tar.gz --strip-components=1 .
```

3. If you run `svn status` at this point, you will see some modified files (`M`), some new (unversioned) files: (`?`) and some deleted (missing) files (`!`).  Before we commit, we need to add the new files (change `?` to `A` ), and remove the deleted files (change `!` to `D`).

```
svn delete $(svn status | sed -ne '/^!/p' | awk '{print $2}')
svn add $(svn status | sed -ne '/^?/p' | awk '{print $2}')
```

4. Review the results with `svn status`, then commit it!

```
svn commit
```